# Self-host web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Когда используется `HttpListener`, у него есть свойство `Prefixes`, туда мы можем добавить строку вида `http://+:8080` и всё будет хорошо работать.
 Я хочу использовать self-host web api, для этого нужно написать: `var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080");`, а строку вида `http://+:8080` он не принимает. Вопрос, соответственно, как ему скормить такую строку. Ну и на всякий, поясните что конкретно означает "+" в данном случае, хотя вроде и так понятно.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: плюс означает, что `HttpListner` будет принимать любые запросы на этом порту, даже те, которые кто-то другой уже принял. Я не пойму, а зачем Вам такое скармливать `HttpSelfHostingConfiguration`?

Comment: @Umed А как иначе сделать тоже самое через `HttpSelfHostConfiguration`, если аргументом мне приходит `http://+:8080`?

Comment: @CRRRRRRRRASH решили проблему?